# is there any use to put "local i = 1" as a single line in a lua terminal?

Tags: lua

Local declaration of a variable applies to the chunk which contains it. So I do not think there is any use to put "local i = 1" as a single line in an Lua terminal. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

When you input any Lua construct that require an `end` statement without providing that `end` statement on the same line, the terminal enters a mode where it accumulates all of the subsequent code until that statement is properly terminated. This mode is denoted by a change in the prompt, going from `>` to `>>`.

In that mode, you can write and use `local` variables just fine. They will be scoped to the end of the block, as normal. Since `do/end` is a block without any real structure, you can build a chunk of arbitrary size in interactive mode.